# Attempting to register a user on my devise app causes undefined method `user_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x00000000020ee0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am still getting this error when I'm trying to register new user, but I can log in to created user after refreshing page.

Here is code which I'm getting on the screen

```
            if options.empty?
              recipient.public_send(method, *args)
            else
              recipient.public_send(method, *args, options)
            end
```

I tried to add

```
    config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
```

It's suggested into [Attempting to register a user on my devise app causes undefined method `user_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x0000000000d9d0>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70413914/attempting-to-register-a-user-on-my-devise-app-causes-undefined-method-user-url/71352145?noredirect=1#comment126119963_71352145) but it won't help me, could you give me any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
data: {tubro: false}
```

to your signup and login page button.
eg :

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up", data: { turbo: false } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question:
0

I am still getting this error when I'm trying to register new user, but I can log in to created user after refreshing page.

Here is code which I'm getting on the screen

```
        if options.empty?
          recipient.public_send(method, *args)
        else
          recipient.public_send(method, *args, options)
        end
```

I tried to add

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
```

answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71920869/19091539

thanks, helper.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).